# Unable to find C Documentation for Error Codes

Tags: typescript, vscode-extensions, visual-studio-extensions, error-code, diagnostics

I'm developing an extension for Visual Studio Code (in Visual Studio Code) and I'm trying to access the error codes of the messages I'm receiving by using the following code:

```
vscode.languages.onDidChangeDiagnostics((e) => {
     e.uris.forEach((uri) => {
         const diagnostics = vscode.languages.getDiagnostics(uri);

         diagnostics.forEach((diagnostic) => {
             let errorCode = diagnostic.code;
         });
     });
});
```

I've been able to infer what these error codes mean by comparing the error codes (from diagnostic.code) to the messages (diagnostic.messages) but I haven't been able to find offical documentation that provides information about what each of the error codes mean - hence, does anyone know where I can find the official documentation that provides information about these error codes.

Side note: My user is using the C language and the C/C++ extension provided by VSC.

Comment: "I haven't been able to find offical documentation for this". So, for what? For the error codes? Messages? Or the relationship between codes and messages? To ask a good question, make things clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you know a little bit about VS Code internals, the error codes and messages come from language extensions, such as C/C++ extension from Microsoft.

The language extension, however, doesn't work on such things itself, but delegate the responsibilities to the language client and language server. Depending on the C language server/compiler you actually use, the error codes/messages can differ significantly.

For example, if your project is compiled by Visual C++ compiler, you can read Microsoft official documentation to learn what are the warnings/errors you should expect.

Other C compilers might or might not have similar articles.

### References

- https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#provide-diagnostics
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/c-cpp-build-errors?view=msvc-170

Comment: Thanks for the info and links, but I wasn't able to find the information I'm looking for - specifically because the error codes I'm receiving doesn't match the error codes in the documentation, even though I'm using the Visual C++ compiler.

Comment: For example, I'm receiving the error code: 20, for the message: Identifier "__ " undefined, and error code: 65, for the message: Expected a ;.